# how to get new instance of module

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, node-modules

I hvae the following module in NodeJS:

File: collection_item.js

```
var items = [];
var exports = module.exports;
exports = module.exports = function() {
};

exports.prototype.addItem = function(item) {
    items.push(item);
};

exports.prototype.deleteItem = function(index) {
    items.splice(index, 1);
};
```

I also have a test with this code:

```
var assert = require("assert");
var itemCollection = require('../../item_collection.js');

describe('Item collection', function(){
    describe('#addItem', function(){
        it('should add object to the collection', function(){
            var collection = new itemCollection();

            collection.addItem({
                test: 'aaa'
            });

            assert.equal(collection.count(), 1); // Success
        });
    });

    describe('#deleteItem', function(){
        it('should delete the given item  from the collection', function(){
            var collection = new itemCollection();

            var item1 = {
                test: 'aaa'
            };

            var item2 = {
                test: 'bbb'
            };

            var item3 = {
                test: 'ccc'
            };

            collection.addItem(item1);
            collection.addItem(item2);
            collection.addItem(item3);

            collection.deleteItem(2);

            assert.equal(collection.count(), 2); // Fails, says it has 3 items
        });
    });
});
```

The problem I have here is that the 2nd test fails. It asserts that there should only be 2 items left in the collection, but says it has 3 items.

This is because the first test added 1 item to the collection. But in the 2nd test I do a:

```
var collection = new itemCollection();
```

How come the collection isn't empty? For some reason it still has the item in it that was added in the first test. I don't understand why this is happening.

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `items` isn't a "private" member.

Try this:

```
var exports = module.exports;
exports = module.exports = function() {
    this.items = [];
};

exports.prototype.addItem = function(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
};

exports.prototype.deleteItem = function(index) {
    this.items.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Comment: This indeed works. But I guess I'm missing something. The NodeJS docs says ***Variables local to the module will be private*** http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules - Why isn't this the case in my code?

Comment: I think you're interpreting it wrong. Yeah, they're private ***to the module*** but inside that module they (your `items`) are shared among *every instance* of your `itemCollection` because you defined it *outside* the constructor function. They aren't private to every instance of `itemCollection`.